# **std::_Atomic_address_as<long const ,std::_Atomic_padded<int> const >**(...) вернул 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, qt, исключения

Из-за чего может вызваться исключение `**std::_Atomic_address_as<long const ,std::_Atomic_padded<int> const >**(...) вернул 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.?`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void Program::Start()
{
    if (IsLaunch())
    {
        VirtualMachine virtualMachine(argv);
        virtualMachine.Start();
    }
}   // На этой сточке вызывается исключение
```

Стектрейс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понадобится больше информации - скажите.

Comment: отрабатывал деструктор VirtualMachine, внутри пытаюсь очистить QList, а там в деструкторе что то пошло не то. Либо объект какой то странный в списке лежит, то ли расстрел памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim это я понял... А вот как решить я не понял(

Comment: а кто его знает. Надо смотреть весь код.

Comment: @KoVadim я уже решил, спасибо